# Google MAP API v3 : I am having issues showing my data on the heatmap

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

I am pretty new to google maps. In my project I basically copied the [heatmap example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap) used my api key,replaced `taxiData` with data pulled from back end which is available in [pastie.org](http://pastie.org/8310641) . the ajax call that pulls data from server side is below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<c:out value="${key}"/>&sensor=false&libraries=visualization">
</script>
 <script>
 var map, pointarray, heatmap;
    var taxiData = [];

    $(function(){
    var d = "2013-08-09T05:51:15Z";
    var postDate = new Date(d);
    var later =new Date(postDate);
    var earlier20 = new Date(later);
    later.setSeconds(later.getSeconds()+ 40);
    $.ajax({
    url: "<spring:url value="/streamview/do/retrieve_coordinates"/>",
    type: "post",
    data:{
    "startTime": earlier20.toISOString(),
    "endTime": later.toISOString()
    }

    }).done(function (data) {

    for(d in data){
         taxiData.push(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(d.lat),parseFloat(d.lng)));
    }



    }).fail(function () {
    alert("FAILED");
    }).always(function(){


    });

     function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(8.300616,-0.922852),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('edowmis-map'),
                mapOptions);

        var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData);

        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: pointArray
        });

        heatmap.setMap(map);
    }

    function toggleHeatmap() {
        heatmap.setMap(heatmap.getMap() ? null : map);
    }

    function changeGradient() {
        var gradient = [
            'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
            'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
            'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
            'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
            'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
            'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
            'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
            'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
        ]
        heatmap.setOptions({
            gradient: heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient
        });
    }

    function changeRadius() {
        heatmap.setOptions({radius: heatmap.get('radius') ? null : 20});
    }

    function changeOpacity() {
        heatmap.setOptions({opacity: heatmap.get('opacity') ? null : 0.2});
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I don't understand why it's not showing anything identifiable as data I passed to it. There is no error in javascript(no firebug error) but my map is just a simple map as if no data was ever passed to it. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Define `not working` - you get a JS error, no map appears, you don't see exactly the results you're expecting on the map, etc?

Comment: No please there is not error. I see a simple map with nothing else referring to the data I passed to it. Thank for the question. I will reformulate then

Comment: Looks like a timing problem to me.  Is that heatmap data available before it is used to create the heatmap (has the AJAX call returned the data)?  There is nothing to force that.

Comment: Yes Ajax has returned the data and that data is what i put in pastie.org.

Comment: Your map works fine if [the data is available before you initialize the map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_heatmapA.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have a closing `</script>` then jump straight into JS again without an opening `<script>` when you do `var map, pointarray, heatmap;`.
Likewise at the end you have some closing JS after your `</script>`

```
</script>

    });
```

This may just be copy-and-paste errors for this question, not errors in your actual code.

It may also be beneficial to add your actual generated JS code, e.g. could it be errors with the lat/lng coordinates?

Comment: that script tag was not in my code, I guess it was introduced when writing this post